# How can i write this if statement?

Tags: python, django

i have some problems with my if statement.

```
        {% for user in users %}
            {% if tournament.tournament_name != user.user_tournament %}
            {% else %}
                <p>{{ user.user_first_name }} {{ user.user_last_name }}</p>
            {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

```
class TournamentUsers(models.Model):
    user_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    user_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    user_tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_last_name + ' ' + self.user_first_name
```

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    data = models.DateField(null=True)
    tournament_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    tournament_creator = models.ForeignKey(Judges, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    tournament_info = models.TextField(max_length=10000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tournament_name
```

```
def content(request, pk):
    tournament = Tournament.objects.get(id=pk)
    users = TournamentUsers.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'ksm_app2/content.html', {'tournament': tournament, 'users': users})
```

I would like to write something in the form of an entry to a particular tournament where the user after clicking on the "join" button is moved to a sheet where the user is asked to enter their name and choose which tournament they want to join. Is it possible to write a conditional instruction that checks if the name of a given tournament is equal to the name of the tournament that the user has chosen and using it to list the users assigned to the given tournament.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `TournamentUsers.user_xxxx_xxx` instead of `user.user_xxxx_xxx`? If not, is your context in your view correct?